# vb.net oop passing data between classes and forms

Tags: vb.net, class, oop, variables

i have made a search box where you can type charetors that are in a name and it will populate a combobox with the results, when you click "ok" button it then pull the rest of the info about that customer from my database. i put the info into the "customer" class and populate all the variables with the info i now need to pass that data into my new form without have to make a new instance of customer. any suggestions ?

.. really sorry for the crap post format, still havent got the editing down :P

```
Public Class customer

    Public Sub New(ByVal CustomerName As String, ByVal CustomerSurname As String)
       Name = CustomerName
       Surname = CustomerSurname
    End Sub

    Friend Name As String
    Friend Surname As String
    Friend Number As String
    Friend Email As String
    Friend PostCode As String

    Public Sub retriveCustomer()
        Dim Mysql_C As New Mysql_Customers
        Dim arrays(2) As String

        arrays = Mysql_C.PullInfo(Name, Surname)
        PopulateCustomer(arrays)
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddCustomer()

    End Sub

    Private Sub PopulateCustomer(ByVal arrays() As String)
        Me.Number = arrays(0)
        Me.Email = arrays(1)
        Me.PostCode = arrays(2)
    End Sub

End Class
```

---

the ok button that calls "customer"

```
Private Sub OkCustomer_button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
  Handles OkCustomer_button.Click
    If csearch.Items.Contains(csearch.Text) Then
        Dim Customer As New customer(returnName(0), returnName(1))
        Customer.retriveCustomer()
        Customer_form.Show()
    Else

    End If
End Sub
```

---

the form i want to pass into and a little example of what i want to happen 
just without having to create a "new customer " and removing all the stored info

```
Public Class Customer_form

    Private Sub Customer_form_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
      Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim custinfo As customer
        Dim pCode As String
        pCode = custinfo.PostCode
    End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Add a constructor to the form class that takes a Customer argument.

Comment: add a property to the form which takes a Cust object, or a method which passes one